# Error installing MySQL

Tags: 20.04, mysql

In Ubuntu 20.04, I try to install mysql server:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

and get the following error:

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 128938
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Following the advice [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-installation-error-dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-5-5-configure), I tried to purge and reinstall, but it did not work - I got the same error.

The error message is not very informative - what can I do to complete the installation?

EDIT: In the file /var/log/mysql/error.log I see the following error messages:

```
2020-07-09T11:15:12.312553Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2020-07-09T11:15:12.312812Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock'
```

Comment: What are the contents of log file?

Comment: I found two error messages there and added them to the question

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error. The issue was that my.cnf contained `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` under `sql_mode`. This has been removed in MySql 8.0.

I had the following in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Removing `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Find locking process with `ps -eaf | grep mysql` and comment if the command returns results. Kill the locking process with `sudo kill -9 <locking-process-number>` and then run `sudo apt purge mysql-server` and try `sudo apt install mysql-server` again.

Comment: Killed live (failed) server. Reinstalled as suggested. Same error.
"Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04. After a purge and reinstall of mysql, I started to see new errors at the end of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

My issues were specifically `Unrecognized variable <name of config variable>`. Those values were in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` which I had chosen to keep from the previous version, but apparently those config variables were no longer supported. I commented them out and the server booted up normally and started working again.

The variables were specifically `query_cache_limit` and `query_cache_size`.